# Download a file from internet inside the app without user intervention

Tags: android

I need to download a file from internet to update some resources files in the path

```
"/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"
```

the method

```
public static void updateDB(){
removeOldCopies();
//how to download a file in a specific directory without open browser????
}
```

should perform this action without user intervention, showing only a progress dialog

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AsyncTask to show a Progress Dialog on the PreExecute() method and hide/dismiss it in the PostExecute() method.

```
ProgressDialog prog = new ProgressDialog(this); // Create Progress Dialog


private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Display progressDialog before download starts
        prog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        prog.hide(); //Hide Progress Dialog else use dismiss() to dismiss the dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InternetManager in = new InternetManager("http://url-to-download");
        in.fileRequest(); 
        return null;
    }
}
```

`in.fileRequest()` will give you the file that you intent to download, Then use [FileOutputStream.write(bytes[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29) to write it into a file.

And finally call the `AsyncTask` through,

```
DownloadFile dd = new DownloadFile();
dd.execute();
```

`InternetManager` class which performing internet releted task.

```
public class InternetManager {
    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpGet httpget;
    HttpResponse httpresponse;
    HttpEntity httpentity;
    String url;
    String response = null;
    byte[] data = null;



    public InternetManager(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public byte[] fileRequest() {
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            data = EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpentity);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("", "File downloaded URL: " + url);
        return data;
         }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I don't know how to download file from an url to a specific folder... if I use intent filter to download the file the app open the browser to download file